# Update over 100 fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

i have 181 fields in my database named S1, S2....S181. I want to update these fields using values from inputs WITH name="S1", .....NAME="S181".

MY CODE IS

```
    $S1=$_POST['S1'];
...
...
    $S181=$_POST['S181'];
  $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"update 'cap' set S1='$S1'......S181='$S181'")
```

I am trying something like

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=181; $i++ ) {
        $(S$i)=$_POST['S$i'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE  `cap4a` SET
                    S$i='$(S$i)' 
            WHERE IDID=".$id) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
    }
```

Is there something wrong in the way I use S$i, because I am getting errors:

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in C:\xampp1\htdocs\update_cap4a.php on line 5" ?
```

Comment: The real solution would be to change your table design. It has major flaws.

Comment: Please fix your formatting by highlighting all your code and clicking the code icon in the textarea's menu bar. It looks lik `{ }`. Also tell us where does `$id` come from?

Comment: and where is your data to be inserted ,S1= $_POST['S1'] all the column data are coming from $_POST

Comment: Sorry but your table design is flawed.

Comment: $id=$_POST['id'];     Why is my table design flawed? It is working but I need help with "FOR"

Comment: ok i see where you get id. Wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to run 181 queries to alter the same row as you do. Instead, run one query that makes all required changes to the row. The code below will work for you:

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];//remove (int) if id IDID is a string
$snippets = [];//holds little snippets eg: S1='value1'
for($i=1;$i<=181;$i++){
    $varname = "S$i"; //S1...S181
    if(!isset($_POST[$varname])) continue;
    $snippets[] = " $varname='$_POST[$varname]' ";
}
$sql = '"UPDATE cap SET '.implode(",",$snippets)." WHERE IDID=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

I don't cover it in this snippet but you need to add at least two things before using this in production:

1. Proper error handling, for when your query fails
2. Prepared statements or escaped values to protect against SQL injection

> Is there something wrong in the way I use S$i

To dynamically create a variable named `S10` and set it to 'value' when `$i=10`, do:

```
$varname = "S$i";
$$varname = 'value'; // $$varname can also be referred to as $S10
```

See [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I would gave done it this way:

```
for ($i = 1; $i<=181; $i++) {
    $key = 'S'.$i;
    $value = $_POST[$key];
    $update[] = "`{$key}` = '".$value."'";

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `cap4a` SET ".join(",",$update)." 
            WHERE IDID=".$id) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
}
```